# is it possible to bind hiddenfield to dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPackage" runat="server" CssClass="ddlPackage" 
Height="24px" Width="250px">
</asp:DropDownList>

<cc1:listsearchextender id="ddlPackage_ListSearchExtender" runat="server" 
enabled="True" targetcontrolid="ddlPackage">
</cc1:listsearchextender>

<asp:Label ID="lblPackage" runat="server" CssClass="errormsg" 
Style="color: Red; display: none;"></asp:Label>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnNewOldType" runat="server" 
Value='<%#Bind("NewOldType") %>' />
```

Is it possible to bind hiddenfield to dropdownlist?

Comment: Why do you want to bind hidden field to the drop down ? Can you specify the exact requirement so that we can answer properly if you are going wrong. Using javascript or jquery you can achieve your goal

Comment: i have 3 column code,name and type.DataTextField=nameand DatavalieField=code.i want to cheque type on chenge of drop downlist.

Comment: Using javascript or jquery how to do?

Comment: check my answer. don't forget to up vote and mark it as an answer if it is helpful. So that it may help other users

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 columns in your DataTable :

- Code
- Name
- Type

And if you want to check the type based on selected code then you can use **SelectedIndexChanged** event of drop down list as mention below :

**Code for Dropdown list :**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPackage" runat="server" CssClass="ddlPackage"
    Height="24px" Width="250px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPackage_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Code Behind :**

```
protected void ddlPackage_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedCode = this.ddlPackage.SelectedValue;

    // Code to check type for selectedCode
}
```